# Lambda function to move objects between S3 storage classes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Use Case: I want to move objects to **S3 Standard - Infrequent Access**, as soon as it gets uploaded to a bucket. I do not want to use lifecycle policy.

Can I use Lambda with SNS here? Like SNS will trigger Lambda function as the object gets uploaded in the bucket and move it to S3 Standard - Infrequent Access?

Thanks.

Comment: It is possible to specify the Storage Class as part of the upload, which would be easier than changing the storage class later. How are you currently uploading the objects? Can you modify the code that is used for the upload?

Comment: As @JohnRotenstein pointed out, directly uploading files to your desired storage class can not only be easier, it can also eliminate unnecessary overhead to move objects around using lambda, not mentioning the additional costs involved.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But the client wants to use this mechanism. Doesn't want to directly upload to IA tier.